# In powerpoint, avoid "click-to-edit" behavior

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

Default in PowerPoint is to start editing a text frame when it's clicked. This is frustrating if I wanted to move it around. I have to click the frame of the box instead, or press ESC to stop editing.

This is click+drag on a text frame:

[image: Result of click+Drag in PowerPoint Text Frame]

Is there a setting for this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior cannot be changed.

If you wish to select the text object, then click the object's frame.
Clicking on the text itself edits the text.

Comment: I found a "workaround" - if you hold `SHIFT` while clicking, it starts moving the object (although in 90 degree directions). Release shift again. Product is now being moved.

Comment: That is so NEAT!

Answer (score 0):

Pressing ESC not only stops text editing, it leaves the shape *containing* the text selected. This accomplishes the same thing as @harrymc's suggestion but is sometimes easier than clicking exactly on the edge of a text box or other shape.

Click anywhere in the text

Press ESC

Move the shape (mouse or arrow keys)

Comment: While you are correct, this won't really work because if you do click, escape and then do a drag with your mouse, you end up selecting the object again.. same problem. Unless you drag from the edge.

Comment: Depending on how much you need to move the text box, true.  For minor moves, the arrow keys will move the text box, once it's selected via the ESC.

Answer (score 0):

Add some bottom margin to all text fields. Then you can click directly into the white space below the text and move the text field without activating text editing mode.
[image: text field with bottom margin added]
Or, in your own example, just click left or right next to the text.